# How to calculate the amount of wetness in water

Tags: python

In Python, how can I create a program that calculates the number molecules in a wet piece of water?

Comment: Well you already seem to have figured out the difficult parts. What's holding you back? Do you know how to write a function? Do you know how to concatenate strings?

Comment: Don't edit your question to ask a new one but instead open a new post for it. The edit you made invalidated the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input` to request a year, the use `str.format` to create a date string

```
def get_year():
    year = input('Enter a year: ')
    return '1/1/{}'.format(year)
```

For example

```
>>> get_year()
Enter a year: 1975
'1/1/1975'
```

Once you have your new date, you can just continue to do what you showed in your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
from datetime import datetime
startyear = input('Please enter a start year: ')
startdate = datetime.strptime(startyear+'-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
today = datetime.now()
numberofdays = today - startdate
print('The number of days from {0} to today is {1}'.format(startdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), numberofdays.days))
```

---

Please enter a start year: 2018

The number of days from 2018-01-01 to today is 76

Comment: Hi. This does work, but is it at all possible if I could create a program like this where the computer knows what year it is without obtaining a user input, for example replacing 'startyear' with 'now.year'? I've tried that but there's a problem because now.year is not recognized as a string. Any help?

Comment: I've tried doing this:


 from datetime import datetime
Now = datetime.now()
StartDate = datetime.strptime(Now.year+'-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
Today = datetime.now()
NumberOfDays = (Today - StartDate)